# Fail to call API in Powerquery Excel-

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to bring data into Excel via API from a database.

But I am getting at the end a message:

> "We couldn't authenticate the credentials provided. Please try again".

The token is coming fine but after that I cannot go further.

The API has got header and body (that I think I cannot define without using code).

```
let
    // Your token retrieval function
    GetAuthToken = () =>
        let
            body = [UserName="user", Password="pass"],
            apiUrl = "https://test.com/test/api/v1/interop/logon",
            headers = [#"Content-Type" = "application/json"],
            response = Web.Contents(apiUrl, [Headers = headers, Content = Json.FromValue(body)]),
            responseText = Text.FromBinary(response),
            token = responseText
        in
            token,

 // Your API data retrieval function
    GetApiData = (apiUrl as text, token as text) =>
        let
                    headers = [
                #"Authorization" = "Bearer " & token,
                #"Content-Type" = "application/json",
                #"accept" = "application/json"
            ],
            requestBody = [
                ResultType = "Hierachical",
                FilterConditions = {
                    [EntityName = null, Filter = null, Sort = null]
                },
                PageNumber = 1,
                PageSize = 25,
                ProjectionOnly = false,
                Parameters = {}
            ],
            response = Json.Document(
                Web.Contents(
                    apiUrl,
                    [
                        Headers = headers,
                        Content = Json.FromValue(requestBody),
                        ManualStatusHandling = {400} // Add this line to handle 400 Bad Request responses
                    ]
                )
            )
        in
            response,

    // Call the token retrieval function
    Token = GetAuthToken(),

    // Call the API data retrieval function using the token and get data
    ApiData = GetApiData("https://test.com/test/api/v1/interop/test", Token)  //
```

Replace with your API endpoint

```
// Return the data
```

in
ApiData

The aim to connect an Excel file with my database via API web. Initially, to get the token (which is coming fine) and then to call API file.

The API was successful in postman
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0htYP.png) [body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPVm1.png)

Comment: have you tried this successfully in postman?

Comment: Yes it was successful in postman, I have added pictures in the initial post

Comment: Another way getting error:Web.Contents failed to get contents  bad request 400
let
getProjects= let 
relpath = "/api/v1/interop/test",
Body = "{""ResultType"":""Hierarchical"",""FilterConditions"":{""EntityName"":null,""Filter"":null,""Sort"":null},""PageNumber"":1,""PageSize"":25,""ProjectionOnly"":false,""Parameters"":{}}",
Source =Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://test.com",[RelativePath = relpath,
Content = Text.ToBinary(Body), Headers = [
#"Content-type" = "application/json",
Authorization = "Bearer tokentext"]])),
response = try Source otherwise null
in Source
in getProjects